# Migrating WSUS 3.0 from SBS2011 to Server 2012 member server?

Tags: wsus, windows-sbs-2011

According to this blog post, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wsus/2016/01/22/for-those-on-wsus-3-0-sp2-or-sbs-2011/ it should be possible to migrate the WSUS services from the SBS 2011 server to another member server, so that the latest WSUS can be used and allow servicing for Windows 10 domain members.  Another TechNet article (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852339.aspx) details how to do the migration, but what additional steps are needed in the case of SBS?  For example, the SBS console application has an area to review / approve updates.  Would that simply be ignored moving forward, or is there additional configuration needed so SBS knows it is no longer the WSUS server.

Comment: As far as removing WSUS from SBS 2011, here is the best info I've found (I'm not the author). http://sangnak.com/disable-wsus-on-sbs-2008-or-2011/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the migration according to the documentation from the links in the question.  I did not uninstall WSUS from the SBS server, but I did disable the relevant services in the Services control panel, and used group policy to point member computers to the new WSUS server.  This seems to be working fine.  The SBS Console's Updates tab shows errors trying to determine update status, but I expected this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in one of your Group Policies is a setting that directs your clients to a particular WSUS server. You need to find that setting and change it there.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's specific to SBS and it is part of the migration documentation.

Comment: There is nothing specific to SBS. Once you migrate your WSUS server, you change Group Policy so that the clients know which server to connect to, and then that's it. You should probably also un-install the WSUS role on the SBS after you've used the new server for a while.

Comment: The reason I asked is because in some ways SBS is a different beast than normal Windows.  For example, you'd normally be advised against running Exchange on a domain controller, but that's the only supported configuration with SBS.  Likewise, its advised to not uninstall Sharepoint from SBS even if you don't plan to use it because it causes a bunch of other issues.  Which is the purpose of my question, to ensure that WSUS can sucessfully be moved from the SBS server to another member server without issue and if this is "supported."